# How to find the "elbow" of a graph?

Tags: derivatives

I have a function of one variable.  In this graph, we can see that there are a couple of places where the graph "bends" a lot -- a local maximum of "bending", if you will.  The ordinary second derivative measures "bending" in the $y$ direction, which will be greatest near the singularity (which is at $-1$).  However, if we measure "bending" orthogonal to the tangent line to the graph at a point, then the "bending" is maximized at the two "elbows" near $x=-2$ and $x=0.75$ or so.  Given a function $y=f(x)$, how might I go about finding these elbows?  Presumably, I will set the third derivative of something to 0 and solve for $x$, but that something is not $f$...

[image]

Comment: Don't mind the red text in the image.  Those are other variables, and this is actually a level set.... I've got a dozen dozen dozen of these very-similar-but-not-quite graphs.  :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like you are searching for the point where the curvature is greatest. In this case, if $y = f(x)$, use the formula $$\kappa  = \frac{|y''|}{\left(1 + \left(y'\right)^{2}\right)^{3/2}}.$$ This will give you the curvature for every $x$ that exists in the domain. Now, to get the value of $x$ whose curvature is greatest, solve for $$\frac{d\kappa}{dx} = 0$$ to get the extreme values, and if necessary, solve for $$\frac{d^{2}\kappa}{dx^{2}} = 0$$ to check which ones are the maxima.

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is to maximize the [curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature). A formula for the curvature of the graph of a function $y=f(x)$ can be found on the same page [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Graph_of_a_function). As you can see from that formula, the curvature does not involve the third derivative, it is instead proportional to the second derivative, with a proportionality constant that depends only on the first derivative.

Comment: But if I'm maximizing the curvature, then I would take a derivative of that, which would involve the third derivative of $f$.  :)

Comment: That's a good point. But it's not the third derivative itself that you would set to zero.